# Unable to select multiple rows in kendo grid using Ctrl key

Tags: html, kendo-grid

I have set selectable field in KendoGrid as "multiple,row" but still I am not able to select multiple rows using Ctrl key though it is working fine with Shift key.

Earlier it was working fine but after I had set virtualization in grid, it stopped working. Then I removed virtualization but still it is not working correctly since then. I have even restarted Visual studio, closed all the sessions but to no effect.

Can anyone please suggest a solution.

Please find the code below:

```
var sampleData = [];

var sampleDataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({       
    data: sampleData ,
    autoBind : false
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({                    
    dataSource: sampleDataSource,
    height: 440,
    selectable: "multiple",
    sortable: true,
    columns:[                         
        {field: "Year", width:50, title: "Year"},
        {field: "Name", title: "Name"}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Please add your code for the grid.

Comment: Added, please have a look

Comment: I've been testing your code in [this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/edUDa), but I haven't been able to reproduce your problem. Is there any javascript that uses this grid? Be sure to look at this [Documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/selection) on grid selection if you haven't already.

Comment: Sorry, I was adding option tag to kendo grid due to which selection was not possible via ctrl key.. changed it to label and its working fine now..